# Why function is not taking parameter

Tags: solidity, contract-development, remix, contract-deployment, function

I have written following simple solidity code

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.0; 
contract C1 {
function f()   {
g(8) ;    // simply passing an integer to another function
}
function g( uint x)  returns (uint )
{
   uint b = x ;
   return b ;    
}
}
```

Now as per my understanding , function `g` should have taken 8 as parameter . The value should have been `x=8` , thereby equating b also to 8 and function `g` returning 8 .

However , I don't know why but function `g` is taking paramter from me i.e. user instead of taking 8 .
[image]

Can anyone please tell me what is wrong here ?

Comment: In remix, both functions are deployed.. thats why function f does take any parameter and g takes uint as parameter.. if you dont want to see g function then u can give private to the function..

Comment: There are multiple problems with your code (function is not a view / pure, old solidity version, missing return statement, etc.). I propose you read up on the function syntax: https://solidity-by-example.org/view-and-pure-functions/

Comment: @ikijong I tried using all those public/view/pure etc. I am a newbie in solidity so thought that  maybe those are causing some issue that is why remove them. Can you please help me in resolving my it is not taking parameter ?

Comment: You can define the variable in `storage` to make it persistent between calls. But even need that would not change the interface